# How can I delete the last X blocks from my local copy of the blockchain and retrieve them again from the network?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain

I think my blockchain has an error sometime within the last day. How can I wipe out a bunch of blocks and get them from the network again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks n
```

Where *n* is the number of blocks you want to remove from the end of the blockchain.